# How to resolve hamcrest jar file error in creating new project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, jar, hamcrest

I got this error while creating new project in android studio,I have checked the library and have hamcrest-core-1.3.jar file .Please help me

```
    Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not download hamcrest-core.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar'.
  > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar'.
     > jcenter.bintray.com
```

Answer (score 6):

the error is not because of hamcrest-core-1.3.jar file. it seems gradle cannot connect to jcenter and download the junit.jar . So, make sure of your internet connection and rebuild your project. normally gradle downloads all necessary jars. if it dosent try to update your build tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your build.gradle Module:app

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
        }}
```

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following lines from build.gradle Module:app under **dependencies**

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

Comment: It will be good to add an explanation on why removing these lines will help

Comment: This actually really worked out for me.  Kudos!  But why then?  Is there an explanation behind this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, When I created a new project I encountered this issue.
To fix it I removed the dependency below from build.gradle Module:app.

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

After that and rebuild project the problem never happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, the gradle could not access jar repositories in my case.

You probably need to:

1. first make sure you are connected to internet
2. setup the proxy settings in Android Studio (especially if you are using it from your work environment/network) OR connect to an open network

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle.properties and comment all systemProp proxys and resync

its work for me

- Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Disable Gradle offline mode under
File > Settings > Build, Execution , Deployment > 
Global Gradle settings 
Disable offline work